# Need clarification involving polynomial fields and the set of all residue classes

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help understanding how to get to the answer of this exercise.

> Find a fourth-degree polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2\left[x\right]$(polynomial field with coefficients 0 or 1) whose roots are the four elements of the field $\mathbb{Z}_2\left[x\right]/\left(x^2+x+1\right)$(notation for modulo $x^2+x+1$). As hint use the Factor Theorem.

I know the answer is $x^4+x$, but I don't understand the logic behind what I did or if it is correct.

The Factor Theorem says "Let $F$ be a field and $F\left[x\right]$ its polynomial ring, then $f\left(x\right)\in F\left[x\right]$ has root $a\in F$ iff $x-a$ is a factor of $f\left(x\right)$."

The four elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2\left[x\right]/\left(x^2+x+1\right)$ are $\left[0\right]$, $\left[1\right]$, $\left[x\right]$ and $\left[x+1\right]$ and I know $\left[0\right]$ and $\left[1\right]$ can be expressed as $0,1\in\mathbb{Z}_2$, so the expressions $x-\left[0\right]$ and $x-\left[1\right]$ are in $\mathbb{Z}_2\left[x\right]$ and make sense to me. But the expressions $x-\left[x\right]$ and $x-\left[x+1\right]$ don't make sense for me to say they are in $\mathbb{Z}_2\left[x\right]$, but it turns out that $x^4+x$ is the product of these 4 polynomials of degree 1.

Should I maybe think of at first making a polynomial in $\left(\mathbb{Z}_2\left[x\right]/\left(x^2+x+1\right)\right)\left[x\right]$? And then I found out I'm "lucky" and all coefficients end up to be either $\left[0\right]$ or $\left[1\right]$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elements of your field (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_4$) verify $\alpha^4 = \alpha$ (Frobenius identity) so you could conclude from here.

You can however use the overkill method of the theorem which is to compute the product of $(T-\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in F = \mathbb{F}_2 [x] / (x^2+x+1)$ (be careful though to use different notations for indeterminates, e.g. like I did here using $T$ instead of $x$) but yes you will be lucky, it will give a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[T]$.
This is completely normal since for every element $\alpha \in F$, its conjugates are also in your field

Either way, the polynomial is:
$$P(T) = T^4 + T$$

Comment: You use $T$ for the indeterminate in the polynomial field with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2\left[x\right]/(x^2+x+1)$, but then use it again as the indeterminate in $\mathbb{F}_2\left[T\right]$. Are you implying that it can no longer be $\mathbb{F}_2\left[x\right]$? Because our construction requires the indeterminate to be outside of both rings, which isn't necessarily true for $x$.

Comment: what I meant by *in* was just $P \in \mathbb{F}_2 [T] \subset F[T]$, not its coefficients your comment is one more reason to be cautious with your choices of indeterminate. A reasonable choice would simply be $[x] = \alpha$ and only use $\alpha$ so that you don't get more confused... $\alpha$ is an element of a field but $T$ is not it is an indeterminate

Comment: With what you say, instead of writing $x - [x]$ which does not make any sense, write $T - [x]$ or $T- \alpha$

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other. To rephrase my question, I was wondering if $\mathbb{F}_2\left[T\right]$ is equal to $\mathbb{F}_2\left[x\right]$. And I argued that they aren't necessarily equal since $x$ and $T$ are indeterminates outside of different rings.

Comment: They are isomorphic algebras... it is really a choice of notation: my remark is your problem is wrongly set since you use both times $x$ as variable to define the algebra of polynomials and the field $F$ and you clearly shouldn't